# Building a 50' string of LED lights for patio

Tags: led-strip

I cannot understand the Ohm's law thing.  I'll make this simple and pray for an answer.

I have an adjustable "buck converter".  It can take 4-38 VDC into it and step it down to 1.25-36 VDC out.

So, I connected 12 VDC/3,000 mA to it and, with the tiny adjustment screw, adjusted it to put out 3.2 VDC (no idea what the mA output is) which is what the 100 LED lights are.  (3.0-3.2 Vdc rated)

I took a bread board and plugged in 100 of these LEDs and touched them to the "out" voltage of 3.2 and VOILA!  All lights lit up.  Is that it?  Don't need any resistor in the line.  Was it that simple?  Can I now build a 32' or 100' string and start hanging lights, with no further adjustments?

Comment: The Ohm's law thing applies to resistors and you haven't got any so it's irrelevant.

Comment: LEDs are inherently current-mode devices.  What you are describing with a specific *voltage* is some LED based *product* of unknown internals, which makes for an unanswerable question.  Then there's the question of things being outdoors.  Realistically you should buy a suitable complete outdoor lighting *system*.

Comment: I dont understand "unknown internals".

Comment: It's simply 3 VDC led's.  So I powered them with 3.2 volts of DC and they lit.  What else would I need?  I have been told that each led is approx. 1/2 milliamp.

Comment: The "unknown internals" controls the current to the 100 LED string or whatever the product is making series resistors unnecessary. You can probably add more in parallel, but since you have no reliable information about the current capacity of the power supply or the current requirement of the LED product, you have no idea how many you can connect without destroying the power supply.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I now build a 32' or 100' string and start hanging lights, with no further adjustments?

Possibly, but you shouldn't.  There are several problems:

- You have no current regulation, which means that you are depending on each LED to have a similar voltage drop, and for that voltage drop to be stable.  Since voltage depends on things like temperature, age, etc and you plan to put these outside, that is recipe for disaster.
- Given the very low voltage, you will need a thick cable to avoid voltage drop in the lines causing the distant LEDs to be dimmer (or not light up at all).  Since you are talking about a 100 ft cable (each way), that is going to be either a very heavy cable or very dim LEDs.

A better way to do this is to put 10 (or more) LEDs in series to build up a 32v circuit and then put a current limiting resistor in series.  This has two big advantages:

- It averages out the variation in individual diodes while regulating the current so you don't blow them out when the temperature changes.
- It reduces the amount of current needed by a factor of 10, which will greatly extend the cable length you can use.